# LibGdx error when I first install it

Tags: java, android, libgdx

This error appears in the libGdx logs:

```
Generating app in C:\big ree Executing 'C:\big ree/gradlew.bat clean --no-daemon' FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong: Could not determine java version from '10.0.1'. * Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Done! To import in Eclipse: File -> Import -> Gradle -> Gradle Project To import to Intellij IDEA: File -> Open -> build.gradle To import to NetBeans: File -> Open Project...
```

Can somebody please help me understand this error.

Comment: You have java 10 in your system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem occurs with any java version above 1.8. The Gdx setup app will not work with the latest versions of java.

To fix:

1. Uninstall all jres and jdks
2. Download and install jdk1.8.0_172 which can be found [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).
3. Be happy or complain about it on GitHub.